# How can I strip the data:image part from a base64

Tags: php, base64, preg-match, php-5.3

How can I strip data:image part from base64 string?

Sometime I have data:text/plain, data:image/jpeg , data:image/png

How can I do it one regular expression . Currently I am using the following code.

```
preg_replace('#data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $file)
```

but this is just for image type

Comment: Simply `str_replace` it with nothing? ;)

Comment: but I dnt know what will be the type either image or text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data URI scheme is made of the following format.

```
data:[<media type>][;charset=<character set>][;base64],<data>
```

Based on the above structure, here is a REGEX for the same. Strip out the REGEX match and you've got your data.

```
data:(\w+/[+-.\w]+)?(;charset=([^"'])+)?(;base64)?,
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ft_cMUVwwI2IHXkG)